# How do I access the self declared attributes submitted by a button?

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple button and added a few self-declared attributes(postid and author).

```
    <%for(var blog of user.posts){%>
      <button type="submit" id="likebtn" onclick="likedpost()" 
       postid="<%=blog._id%>" author="<%=user.username%>">Like</button>
<%}%>
```

This is a function I have defined.

```
function likedpost(){
 var id = document.getElementById("likebtn").getAttribute("postid");
 var author = document.getElementById("likebtn").getAttribute("author");
 console.log("id form likedpost function =" +id+"and author of this post is="+author);
 console.log('post liked');
 }
```

For every blog item when I am clicking its respective button it is giving me the same blog._id for all the items in the console.log(). I can see in the inspector that each button has a different blog._id. I think the problem is that it is finding the first element with id = "likebtn" as each button has the same id i.e it is giving back the first value. How do I fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the same ID tag for more than one element. Intead, you can just pass a reference to the button itself through the function and access the attributes. Best practices are to access them as `data-attributes` via the `dataset` property

```js
function likedpost(el) {
  let id = el.dataset.postid;
  let author = el.dataset.author;
  console.log("id form likedpost function =" + id + "and author of this post is=" + author);
  console.log('post liked');
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="likebtn" onclick="likedpost(this)" data-postid="<%=blog._id%>" data-author="<%=user.username%>">Like</button>
```